# Setting Session in MVC3 when the class not inherited from controller or helper

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, session

I would like to write and read data to Session even if my class not inherited from controller or helper.  Something like this:

```
 public class User
{

        public void CreateSession()
        {
            Session["key"]=data;

        }

        public void ReadSession()
        {
            data=(string)Session["key"];
        }


}
```

Important thing - **I need to get instance of `User` class in some actions
 and views**. Am I be able to inherit `User` class from controller or
 helper. Because I've already try that, but I got some errors.

How can I achive this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you need to access it in the view?  Just pass it via ViewBag to your view.

Comment: Because I am using that class for authorazion control, on master page from User class instance I get some data about name, id etc.

Comment: You should not be using session for authorization control.  You should be using something IPrincipal based, otherwise you are open to session theft vulnerabilty.

Comment: Yes you're right. Actually I use cookie with encription data to store user data. but because of that problem "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067289/" now I am trying to find another solution for it. Also I may encript data before set session.

Answer (score 1):

HttpContext.Session will work, it's a static available anywhere to an assembly that references System.Web.

If your code is in your main website assembly, this should work well.  If it's not, you'll have to create a dependency on System.Web which you may or may not want to do.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried to call Session HttpContext.Sesion and System.Web.HttpContext.Sesion but both retunt null value. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Actually if you access HttpContext.Current.Session outside controller (for example in your global.asax.cs), you will notice it is null.

Answer (score 1):

You should do these kind of things in your controller.

You can access HttpContext directly, but that's not "the ASP.NET MVC way", and you loose some of the advantages of using MVC in the first place. Like making testing harder, and directly coupling your application to HttpContext...

Also, if it's a new session, or Session["key"] is not set for some reason, `data=(string)Session["key"];` would throw a null reference exception.