# Azure Caching issue(some setting on Azure account and web.config file for Sessions)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, session, azure, web-config, cloud

I have a problem about web.config file which is exist on MVC3 Cloud project.

As you know for using Sessions on Cloud you need to create name space on Azure account Caching side. And get some custom settings for web.config data from azure and copy them in your project.

Till here everything works fine. But if add some additional line in my web.config file like this.

```
 <appSettings>
    <add key="key1" value="value1" />
    <add key="key2" value="value2" />
 </appSettings>
```

than my project getting crash. Sessions has decided not carrying any data anymore.
İf I remove that lines everything works fine again.

Do you have any idea what cloud be wrong?

By the way I am using these key and value pairs for set and read cookie settings.

Thanks in advance....

Comment: Since you said that everything works fine if you removed these AppSettings I don't think the there's anything wrong on the configuration of your WAAF Caching. There's no relationship between the WAAF Caching config and AppSettings. I guess there's something wrong on your code, maybe the business logic to mess it up. Can you please provide more information, or some codes.

Comment: well, business logic may mess it up. But there is no error to find why it happens. Some codes here related those appSettings
 
        private void ReadConfigCookieName()
        {
            cookieName = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["key1"];
            inspectorCookie = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["key2"];
        }

than I use that cookie names to write or read some data. Again if I don't use appSettings key and value, or not set cookieNames from appSettings key, incredibly WAAF Caching I mean my Sessions works fine. otherwise not.

Comment: Strange. I'm not sure if this is because you used System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings, or you used the cookie. Anyway this is a strange problem. Did you try to just load AppSetting, and just read/write cookie, to verify which one caused the problem.

Comment: Yes I've tried. there is no problem İf don't read/write cookie. So as you say WAAF Caching and AppSettings not related. Even though isnt it strange something related with read/write cookie and WAAF Caching?

Comment: First off all Thaks Shaun Xu. I've found the problem. Actually rather than problem it is a bug I guess.

 

As I thougt there is no relation WAAF Caching config and AppSettings. In my case after setting Cookie name, for creating new cookie I was using 

"HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Clear();"
line for delete existing ones. The problem is here, that line delete cookies but also delete Sessions too (on Azure).

Isn't it bug?

Comment: I don't think it's a bug. As you know by default ASP.NET will store your session id in a cookie, so that the server can identify you and get the content of your session from, in your case, WAAF Cache. But in your code you cleared all cookies. I guess this will remove the session cookie as well. Might be help if you just remove the cookies you want instead of clear.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to get setup with Azure Session is to use the ASP.NET Universal Providers
 using NuGet simply type:

> PM> Install-Package System.Web.Providers

Once it's include in youre project you can use SQLAzure, AzureStorage table or the Azure Appfabric caching.

You can read more about the provider here: [The Magic Provider (also call Universal Providers)](http://www.frankysnotes.com/2011/08/magic-provider-also-call-universal.html)